# Indexing by counting rows and assign same index number when condition encountered. Preferably using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to index by number of rows, but if condition met, index number should be repeated.

Let's say that I have the following df

```
df1 <- data.frame(Segment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  Position = c(3, 24, 56, 725, 4, 4, 4, 45))
```

If I use  `df1["length"]<- seq.int(nrow(df1))`  I get:

```
Segment Position length
       1        3      1
       1       24      2
       1       56      3
       1      725      4
       2        4      5
       2        4      6
       2        4      7
       2       45      8
```

What I actually would like to get is

```
Segment Position length
       1        3      1
       1       24      2
       1       56      3
       1      725      4
       2        4      5
       2        4      5
       2        4      5
       2       45      6
```

I know it does not make sense to use `seq.int(nrow())` as it is AND I should add an *if* but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the distinct occurances and join:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(Segment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  Position = c(3, 24, 56, 725, 4, 4, 4, 45))

df1 %>%
  left_join(df1 %>%
              distinct(Position) %>%
              mutate(my_length = row_number()),
            by = "Position")

#Segment Position my_length
#1       1        3         1
#2       1       24         2
#3       1       56         3
#4       1      725         4
#5       2        4         5
#6       2        4         5
#7       2        4         5
#8       2       45         6
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `base` solutions

```
df1$length <- cumsum(c(T, df1$Position[-1] != df1$Position[-nrow(df1)]))
```

or

```
df1$length <- cumsum(c(T, diff(df1$Position) != 0))
```

***Output***

```
#   Segment Position length
# 1       1        3      1
# 2       1       24      2
# 3       1       56      3
# 4       1      725      4
# 5       2        4      5
# 6       2        4      5
# 7       2        4      5
# 8       2       45      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
library(dplyr)
#Unique vals in Position
dfu <- df1[!duplicated(df1$Position),'Position',drop=F]
dfu$Length <- 1:dim(dfu)[1]
#Merge
df1 %>% left_join(dfu)

  Segment Position Length
1       1        3      1
2       1       24      2
3       1       56      3
4       1      725      4
5       2        4      5
6       2        4      5
7       2        4      5
8       2       45      6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1$length <- cumsum(c(1, diff(df1$Position) != 0))

  Segment Position length
1       1        3      1
2       1       24      2
3       1       56      3
4       1      725      4
5       2        4      5
6       2        4      5
7       2        4      5
8       2       45      6
```

Comment: If the second `Position` is `4`, not `24`, your code gets `1 2 3 4 4 4 4 5`. The OP doesn't specify the condition so I'm not sure whether this is reasonable or not.

Comment: That's a great point. Let me revise just for posterity. The post is closed already so...